# Advantages of using two Kafka Connect Sink connectors for topics with similar data and workload?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have two Kafka topics (`topic_A` and `topic_B`) with identical partitioning (4 partitions) and similar data structures. Both topics require the same processing work.

Currently, I'm considering a single Kafka Connect Sink connector to write data to BigQuery, with `tasks.max` set to 8. This setup will run within a Kubernetes (K8s) cluster configured to scale up pods/workers based on topic latency, pod CPU, or pod memory usage.

Are there advantages to using two separate Sink connectors (one per topic) instead of a single connector for this scenario? If so, what are they? I'm primarily interested in factors like performance, fault tolerance, scaling flexibility, and overall management.

Answer (score 0):

Two connectors can be given different configurations, if needed. Partitions isn't the only thing that matters. Authentication, serialization format, record sizes, etc will need to be similar as well.

Fault tolerance is also a factor since the tasks can rebalance and any failure could halt the complete task, so stopping it for all topics being consumed

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer!
You mentioned failures halting the entire task. Did you mean the entire **connector**? My understanding is that with `tasks.max` equal to the total partition count, each task would handle a specific topic-partition, minimizing the impact across topics in a single-connector setup. Did I not understand you correctly?

Comment: Tasks run on individual threads, which can independently fail. Partitions can then be reassigned to tasks such that 7/8 active tasks would be running and 2 partitions could be assigned to one task. You'll want JMX monitoring to check total task status